# sed contents of file appended to specific line in another file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a rather complicated `sed` script which writes the contents of a file into a single line comma separated list in a new file.

I want to read that file and write it to end of a specific line of a another file. What would really be better is to read the original file, write the comma separated list directly to the specified line in the new file and skip the middle man.

```
sed -n '/# FirstMark/,/# EndMark/p' client_list.formal|grep -v "#"|awk -F\< '{print $2}'|awk -F\> '{print $1}'|xargs|sed -e 's/ /,\ /g'|sort -u|sed -i /writes all this stuff to end of specified line > file.txt
```

The break down is:

1. `sed -n '/ # FirstMark/` (begin reading at this string)
2. `,/# EndMark/p'` (stop reading at this string)
3. `client_list.formal` (from this file)
4. `grep -v "#"` (remove all the commented out lines)
5. `awk -F\< '{print$2}'|awk-F\> '{print $1}'` (print everything between < and >)
6. `xargs|sed -e 's/ /,\ /g'|sort -u` (put it all on the same line, add commas, and sort for unique only)
7. The final bit should write all of that output to the end of a specified line in a new file.

My current work just writes that to a file. Then I sed -i that file to then end of every line of another file (that file has only one line. But there will be other files with multiple lines and each line will have it's own list and all lists will be built from the one source file.)

So far I have seen how to insert it into a file, a specific line, append it to the end of file, but not to a then end of a specified line. Have I over thought this? I feel like I have over thought this.

**Example client_list.formal**

`# Formal Client Name1`
`Contact Lastname,Firstname      <email@address.tld>`
`Contact Lastname,Firstname      <email@address.tld>`
`# Formal Client Name2`
`Contact Lastname,Firstname        <email@address.tld>`

**Example file written to:**

email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld

**Example file to insert to:**

`alias1: email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld`
`alias2:`
`alias3:email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld`

**Expected File format when operation is complete:**

`alias1: email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld`
`alias2: email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld,`
`alias3: email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld, email@address.tld`

Comment: Post an example input file, file to insert into and expected output.

Comment: Honestly, I think it's complicated enough that daisy chaining awk/sed here is too much. Is there a particular reason you're avoiding `perl`?

Comment: Mostly because I don't know any programming languages. I am teaching myself bash scripting as I go along. I have picked up the Python book form O'Reilly this week. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly - the chain of commands is big enough that I think it's time to break out a programming language like `perl`.

The task you're trying to do could be done *something* like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#open your input file
open ( my $email_file, '<', 'client_list') or die $!;
#read all the lines with <email@somewhere>, and join them on a ','
my $address_list = join ( ",", map { m/<(.*)>/ } <$email_file> );
print "Inserting $address_list\n"; 
close ( $email_file ); 

#open filename     
open ( my $file2, '<', "insert_file_name" ) or die $!;
open ( my $results_file, '>', "output_file" ) or die $!;
#iterate file2.  
while ( my $line = <$file2> ) {
    # if condition matches, replace end of line with the address list above; 
    if ( $line =~ m/alias2/ ) { $line =~ s/$/$address_list/ };
    print {$results_file} $line;
}
close ( $file2 );
close ( $results_file );
```

Comment: I created test case files to look at what this does. I see how it is useful. I will need to learn more about pearl so I can tweak this to grab out selected entries in the email_file and append them to a selected line in the results_file. This is definitely going to require arguments when called from command line.